# Backdrop-filter: blur not working with iOS browsers. Any solution?

Tags: css, responsive, user-experience

I have a backdrop filter applied to a dropdown menu, on desktop and Android browsers there's no problem, but when testing on iOS browsers the blur effect is not applied. Here's my code:

```
.dropdown_menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 60px;
  height: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
```

I tried adding -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px); but had no positive outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is display none at start. Try to change to block at first moment, and the change it by Javascript or something else in realtime. You will resolve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).